# default email not showing up in webform

Tags: webforms, configuration

I had used files of a website to create new website. I had changed the database and user details in settings.php. Now everything is working fine except email settings in webform. It is showing old informations as default.

I need the default email to be "noreply@pharmahelpdesk.net". 
In Configuration > System > Site Information , I had used the same email id. But it is not getting updated. Due to this I am not receiving emails. Please see the images and suggest.

[image].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think here is a option to change default email `admin/config/content/webform`.

[image]